# JSP implicit objects vs PageContext

Tags: java, jsp

While writing a page in JSP, we can either use the implicit variables

```
application,request,session
```

or use the pageContext variable along with pageContext.Application_SCOPE etc.

Why should we use pageContext in place of the implicit variables, and what are the advantages/disadvantages for using either of them.

ex:-
Why use

```
pageContext.setAttribute("Key","Value",pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)
```

vs

```
request.setAtrribute("Key","Value")
```

---

**Edit:**

Nathan Hughes proposed that my question is a duplicate. But the question he , provided a link to elaborates pageContext with respect to ExpessionLanguage while my question actually relates to pageContext with respect to Scriptlets.

**Expression Language** - `${pageContext.session}` - This returns a Session object.
[image: API as given by Eclipse]

**Scriplets** - `<% pageContext.SESSION %>` - This returns a String.
[image: API as given by Eclipse]

The **pageContext** variable has different behavior in the above two Contexts.
So , now that i have established how my question differs, can anyone answer my original question?

Comment: Read the accepted answer on the linked question and also the comments, it directly addresses your question.

Comment: Edited , on how my question might  be diferent

Comment: please be specific, "the behavior appears to be different" is pretty vague.

Comment: Elaborated. Please remove the duplicate in the heading, if you find the reason compelling

Comment: I have improved the reasoning. Do you see it now?